# Error al ejecutar stored procedure en mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

por favor ayuda con este stored procedure en mysql en MariaDB.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El asunto es que al ejecutar el procedure no toma el parametro de entrada sino que hace la consulta con el nombre de la tabla "tabla". alguna idea?

//CODIGO

```
  CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE 
  `obtener_ultimo_registro`
  (IN `tabl` VARCHAR(64) CHARSET utf8, IN `campo` INT) 
  NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY      DEFINER 
  SELECT * FROM tabl ORDER BY campo DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Sin el código del PA ni idea, por favor edita y agrégalo

Comment: listo @Aprendiz

Answer (score 0):

**IMPORTANTE:** Tenga cuidado con problemas de Inyección SQL.

Necesita ejecutar una sentencia dinámica y dependiendo de la versión de MariaDB utilizada, puede tener varias opciones. Aquí una opción:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `obtener_ultimo_registro` (
  IN `tabl` VARCHAR(64) CHARSET utf8,
  IN `campo` INT
) 
NOT DETERMINISTIC
NO SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  CONCAT('SELECT * 
          FROM `', `tabl`, '` 
          ORDER BY ', `campo`, ' DESC 
          LIMIT 1');
```

Ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=d5cb4f9b6689ce6b78cae3b9226f64ab).